# What is exc_fd_set in curl_multi_fdset()?

Tags: c, libcurl

Curl's `curl_multi_fdset` function has the following declaration:

```
CURLMcode curl_multi_fdset(CURLM *multi_handle,
                           fd_set *read_fd_set,
                           fd_set *write_fd_set,
                           fd_set *exc_fd_set,
                           int *max_fd);
```

Curl documentation does not explain the meaning of `exc_fd_set`. What is the meaning of `exc_fd_set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely the same meaning as with `select(2)`, as the function is meant to supply the FD sets for it.

> Those listed in readfds will be watched to see if characters become available for reading (more precisely, to see if a read will not block; in particular, a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file), those in writefds will be watched to see if a write will not block, and those in exceptfds will be watched for exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

I have just updated the [curl_multi_fdset()](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_fdset.html) man page to better explain what the arguments are actually used for:

> If the *read_fd_set* argument is not a null pointer, it points to an
>   object of type fd_set that on returns specifies the file descriptors
>   to be checked for being ready to read.
>
> If the *write_fd_set* argument is not a null pointer, it points to an
>   object of type fd_set that on return specifies the file descriptors to
>   be checked for being ready to write.
>
> If the *exc_fd_set* argument is not a null pointer, it points to an
>   object of type fd_set that on return specifies the file descriptors to
>   be checked for error conditions pending.